# How to update an existing row with HTML on an existing JQuery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have an existing jQuery dataTables object in my html page.

I need to update a few `<a href>` elements in all `<td>`s on the first `<tr>` of the datatables by clicking on a refresh button which triggers an Ajax call to retrieve the new data in JSON.

The `<a href>` elements are dynamically constructed with the hyper links retrieved by Ajax, so I need to have the html for each `<a href>` element.

```
<tr id="LoJXi76DH3" role="row" class="odd">
    <td><a data-transition="pop" data-mini="true" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" href="#deleteThisRunModel" onclick="copyRunModelObjId(&quot;LoJXi76DH3&quot;);" title="Delete this job"><img width="16" height="16" src="css/img/Remove24.png"></a></td>
    <td><span>LoJXi76DH3</span></td>
    <td><span>500</span></td>
    <td><span>Completed</span></td>
    <td><span>Firstname Lastname</span></td>
    <td><span>9/12/2015, 1:07:39 PM</span></td>
    <td><span>9/12/2015, 1:18:47 PM</span></td>
    <td><span>Successful</span><span> </span><a title="Details" class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext" data-transition="pop" data-rel="popup" href="#popupRMDetails_LoJXi76DH3">Details</a></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="View.jsp?res=500&amp;url=myImage.png">View</a><span> </span><a href="myServlet?action=exportForDownload&amp;jobOID=LoJXi76DH3">Download</a></td>
</tr>
```

Just wondering which function/api should I use to get this done?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to replace an entire `<tr>..</tr>` with a brand new or modified `<tr>`, you can do the following.

First locate the row you want to replace in jQuery, either with some id selector or through DOM traversal from an event like this:

```js
var $row = $(this).closest("tr")
```

Let's say you have an brand new HTML row that you'd like to replace it with. This could come from an AJAX call, somewhere on the page, or a modified version of the existing row, or just straight HTML:

```js
var newRow = $("<tr>  <td>1</td> <td>Bob</td> <td><i>23</i></td>  <tr>
```

If this was a plain HTML table, you could just do [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) like this:

```js
$row.replaceWith($(newRow))
```

Buutttt, then DataTables doesn't know about it, so the next time you call [`$dt.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()), it'll change back.  Instead, you have to pass the new info into the DataTable by locating the row in DataTables and then handing it the new info.

> [**`row().data()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) - data represents an array of string values that are the `innerHTML` of each `td`

So we need to convert the above row to something like this:

```js
["1","Bob","<i>23</i>"]
```

Here's a function that converts a row to a data table array:

```js
function TrToData(row) {
   return $(row).find('td').map(function(i,el) {
        return el.innerHTML;
   }).get();
}
```

So the whole thing will look something like this:

```js
$('.replace').click(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr")
    var newRow = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML

    var newRowDataArray = TrToData(newRow)  
    $dt.row($row).data(newRowDataArray).draw();
});
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/5aaa9cmj/)

#### Demon in Stack Snippets

```js
$(function() {
   // initialize table
    var $dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        paging:   false,
        bFilter: false, 
        bInfo: false
    });
    
   // add row
    $('#addRow').click(function () {
        //$dt.row.add( [1,2,3] ).draw();
        var newRow = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML
        $dt.row.add($(newRow)).draw();
    });
    
    // replace row
    $('.replace').click(function () {
      var $row = $(this).closest("tr")
        var newRow = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML
     
        var newRowDataArray = TrToData(newRow)  
  
        //$row.replaceWith($(newRow))
        //data represents an array of string values that are the innerHTML of each td
        $dt.row($row).data(newRowDataArray).draw();
        
    });
    
    function TrToData(row) {
       return $(row).find('td').map(function(i,el) {
         return el.innerHTML;
       }).get();
    }
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hidden</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Replace</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Line 1 <input type="hidden" value="1"/> </td>
      <td>Bob    <input type="hidden" value="Bob"/> </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="18"/> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Replace" class="replace"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>
<button id="addRow">Add New Row</button>

<table id="newRow" style="display:none">
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>Line 2 <input type="hidden" value="2"/>   </td>
      <td>Ann    <input type="hidden" value="Ann"/> </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="21"/> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Replace" class="replace"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect if you need to update a row without using JSON. Thanks!

Comment: I have css classes on my tds ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery for updating a specified row. for this you need to define unique id for each row. then by the following id, you can get the object of the table element and update it by ajax call. let me explain by code. here also shown how to manipulate dynamic links.

```
function updateJobStatus() {
        $("#data-table tr.running").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            var id = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
            //var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'ajaxGetPrintJob.html',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                success: function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    if (textStatus == 'success' && responseData.length > 0) {
                        var id = responseData[0].id;
                        var tagId = responseData[0].voterListTagId;
                        var createdBy = responseData[0].createdByName;
                        var locationType = responseData[0].locationType;
                        var totalJobCount = responseData[0].totalJobCount;
                        var successCount = responseData[0].successCount;
                        var failedCount = responseData[0].failedCount;
                        var status = responseData[0].status;
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(0)').html(id);
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(1)').html('<input name="app_id" id="row'+id+ '" type="checkbox" value="'+id+'" class="case"/>');
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(2)').html('<a href="showPrintJob.html?jobId='+id+'&tagId='+tagId+'&locationType='+locationType+'&w=1024&h=700&load=true&jobName='+responseData[0].name+'" class="popup">'+responseData[0].name+'</a>');
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(3)').html(createdBy);
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(4)').html(totalJobCount);
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(5)').html(successCount);
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(6)').html(failedCount);
                        $(obj).find('td:eq(7)').html(status);

                    }
                }, error: function(responseData) {
                    unblockView();
                }
            });

        });
        setTimeout(updateJobStatus, 20000);
    }
```

here updateJobStatus() function will fire every 20 sec by ajax calling getting data and also manipulate.
here data-table refers the table id.

```
<table summary="search result" id="data-table" class="search-result" cellspacing="0" style="">
```

and the table row should be like,

```
<tr class="<c:if test="${loop.count % 2 !=0}"> odd-row </c:if> <c:if test="${result.status eq 'INITIALIZING'}"> running </c:if>" >
```

Comment: Thanks Ataur. But I tried using JQuery to update the table before it didn't work. This wouldn't update the Datatables rows. :(

Comment: can you check that you are not pulling the same database object  and showing it in the table again, when you called by ajax??

Comment: Either way, you should never manipulate content of a dataTable without using the API. Even if it seems to work, any changes will be lost after redraw because dataTables not is aware of those changes.  dataTables holds all table data in internal variables, and does not check if the table somehow has been altered "unauthorized".